# jquery count first level elements from within .each() loop

Tags: jquery, each

Does anyone know how to count just the first level children of an element from inside a .each() loop?

For example, I have several  lists on my page, like so ...

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item6</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to loop through each  list and determine how many list items it has, except using jQuery .size() is counting the  tags as elements too.  I just need to know how many list items exist.

Additionally, I'm not sure how to do this because using something like jQuery('ul > li').size() isn't accessible from within the .each() loop, because I'm referencing each different  with jQuery(this).  Is there a way to do something like jQuery(this ' > li')?  Cause that's not working for me either :)

here's what i've been trying, but I'm not having any luck:

```
jQuery('ul').each(function() {
    var count = jQuery(this).find('li').size();
    alert(count);
});
```

Comment: `jQuery(this).find('li').length` isn't doing it?

Comment: What's the number you want to get from your example? 13? Or 4, 6, 3?

Comment: I would think $('ul>li').length would do it - although if you have any nested ul, it would count those as well. Is that the problem?

Comment: Just FYI, from the jQuery Documentation: `The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property:

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    var count = $(this).find('li').length;
    alert(count);
});
```

or if you want to select immediate children li tags, you can try:

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    var count = $('> li', this).length;
    alert(count);
});
```

Comment: +1 Yup, this will do it. Another good tip for the OP'er is that `.length` is an easy way to check if an element exists. For example, `if($('#somediv').length){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

'>' [immediateChild selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

you can use `$('> li')` when using `$(this).find()` or alterbatively do,

```
$('ul').each(function(){
  var length = $('>li', this).length;
  alert(length);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. I think it's much better.

```
var rt = 0;
$('ul').each(function() {
    rt++;    
});

alert(rt);
```